# PYSVN: how to set local working folder so I can commit a file?

Tags: python, pysvn

After I get the pysvn client, how can I set the working folder to a specific local working folder belonging to a specific repo?

I'd like to set the working folder so i can then commit changes from there.

I have tried passing in the path to the client but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to call pysvn.Client().checkin() is with the absolute path to the working copy top folder. You should then see from svn log that all the changed files where committed.

By using an absolute path you avoid issues with the current working directory and relative paths.

If this does not help post details of the error message you receive, the version of python, the version of pysvn and your operating system.